# remove duplicate lines in wget output

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, wget

I want to remove duplicate lines in wget output.

I use this code

`wget -q "http://www.sawfirst.com/selena-gomez" -O -|tr ">" "\n"|grep 'selena-gomez-'|cut -d\" -f2|cut -d\# -f1|while read url;do wget -q "$url" -O -|tr ">" "\n"|grep 'name=.*content=.*jpg'|cut -d\' -f4|sort |uniq;done`

And output like this

http://www.sawfirst.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Selena-Gomez-12.jpg

http://www.sawfirst.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Selena-Gomez-12.jpg

http://www.sawfirst.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Selena-Gomez-12.jpg

http://www.sawfirst.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Selena-Gomez-12.jpg

http://www.sawfirst.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Selena-Gomez-760.jpg

http://www.sawfirst.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Selena-Gomez-760.jpg

I want to remove duplicate lines of output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In some cases, tools like [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)) become more appropriate.

Trying to do this with only `wget` & `grep` becomes an interesting exercise, this is my naive try but I am very sure are better ways of doing it

```
$ wget -q "http://www.sawfirst.com/selena-gomez" -O -|
grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" |
grep -i "selena-gomez" |
while read url; do
    if [[ $url == *jpg ]]
    then
        echo $url
    else
        wget -q $url -O - |
        grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" |
        grep -i "selena-gomez" |
        grep "\.jpg$" &
    fi
done | sort -u > selena-gomez
```

In the first round:

```
wget -q "http://www.sawfirst.com/selena-gomez" -O -|
grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" |
grep -i "selena-gomez"
```

URLs matching the desired name will be extracted, in the while loop could be the case that the `$url` is already ending with `.jpg` therefore it will be only printed instead of fetching the content again.

This approach just goes deep 1 level, and to try to speed up things it uses `&` ad the end with the intention to do multiple requests in parallel:

```
grep "\.jpg$" &
```

*Need to check if the `&` lock or wait for all background jobs to finish*

It ends with `sort -u` to return a unique list of items found.

Answer (score 0):

Better try :

```
mech-dump --images "http://www.sawfirst.com/selena-gomez" |
    grep -i '\.jpg$' |
    sort -u
```

Package `libwww-mechanize-perl` for Debian and derivatives.

### Output:

```
http://www.sawfirst.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Selena-Gomez-12.jpg
http://www.sawfirst.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Selena-Gomez-760.jpg
http://www.sawfirst.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Selena-Gomez-404.jpg
...
```